# Formatting XML Label

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

With this XML file -

```
<Instructions>
  <Admin>
  <Instruction>
    Steps must be completed in order.&lt;/br&gt;
    1. Set dates&lt;/br&gt;
    2. Import.&lt;/br&gt;
    3. Generate.&lt;/br&gt;
  </Instruction>
  <Style>
    <padding-left value="50px"/>
    <padding-right value="0px"/>
  </Style>
  </Admin>
</Instructions>
```

And this code -

```
    public void LoadInstructions(String instructionKey) {
        XmlNode instLabel = mPropsDoc.SelectSingleNode("ApplicationProperties/Instructions/Admin/Instruction");
        XmlNode instStyle = mPropsDoc.SelectSingleNode("ApplicationProperties/Instructions/Admin/Style");
        Label ctlInst = new Label();
        ctlInst.Text = instLabel.InnerText;

        foreach (XmlElement styles in instStyle.ChildNodes) {
            ctlInst.Style.Add(styles.Name, styles.Attributes["value"].Value);
        }

        PageContent.Controls.AddAt(0, ctlInst);
    }
```

where PageContent is a ContentPlaceHolder on my page.

The style gets applied to only the first element and the control is rendered as a span control.

Why isn't it being rendered as a Label and why is the style only being applied to the first line?

Comment: What do you mean with "applied to the first line"? Can you give an example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, System.Web.UI.Label element(which I presume you're using), is always rendered as <span>. To create a <label> - you need System.Web.UI.HtmlGenericControl("label").

Answer (score 1):

if you want to kkep the formatting, you nned to get it into a CDATA element

```
<Instruction>
<![CDATA[Steps must be completed in order</br>
               1. Set dates</br>
               2. Import</br>     
               3. Generate</br>]]>
</Instruction>
```

Saying that, I'd mark this lot up and then build the presentation when required, it will continue to be a PIA.